# ERC1155 ID - how to handle BigNumber?

Tags: javascript, erc-1155, gnosis, bignumber, uint256

I'm exploring Gnosis conditional tokens (which are adapted `ERC1155`). The `_mint` method in `ERC1155` requires an `id` that is `uint`. Gnosis has a method called `getPositionId` which converts a
keccak256 hash into a `uint`:

```
    /**
     * @dev Constructs a position ID from a collateral token and an outcome collection
     * @param _collateralToken: ERC20 token collateralizing the position
     * @param _collectionId: ID of the outcome collection associated with this position
     */
    function getPositionId(IERC20 _collateralToken, bytes32 _collectionId) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_collateralToken, _collectionId)));
    }
```

The return value is used as the `id` in the `_mint` function. However, the value is massive (`BigNumber`) and causes overflow issues while working with hardhat tests.

For example, let:

- `_collateralToken` = `0x2Dd78Fd9B8F40659Af32eF98555B8b31bC97A351`
- `_collectionId` = `0x6f6f41ff811f45c6dfe727fcb2a278f07323fb85ec753bece2f9a690cca7a01d`

Then packing these into a keccak256 and then converting to a `uint` generates the return value of `getPositionId`:

- `74229324384859666491956367114251131107901747002219700387957564294760735619703`

Now if I wanted to check the `balanceOf` an `address`, I need to pass in two parameters:

- `balanceOf(address account, uint256 id)`

This requires me to convert the `positionId` into a `uint` using `positionId.toNumber()` but then
the overflow error occurs!

Is there a trivial solution I'm overlooking or should I refactor the `getPositionId` into something more simplistic?

Comment: So the issue you are having is present when you are writing Hardhat test?

Comment: Yes - but it will be present in any frontend dev work because it's a Javascript generated overflow error

Comment: I remember having this issues and solving it by simply sending string instead of number. Instead of number 1000, I would send "1000"